# I have 2 identical IDs but when I try to find if they are equal they are not

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm searching in an array from database, I'm working with MongoDB and Mongoose, for an ID. There are only 1 ID and when I'm trying to find it in the array, it's not found.

I used the function " findIndex() ", but even if there is the ID I'm looking for the result is still -1.

```
exports.getProfile = async (req,res,next) => {
    const targetUser = req.params.userId;
    const loggedInUser = req.session.user._id;

    try{
       let user = await User.findOne({"_id":targetUser});
       const a  = user.positiveRanked.length;
       const b  = user.negativeRanked.length;

       console.log(a,b);
       if(a === 0 && b ===0){
           res.render('profile/profile', {
               user:user,
               pageTitle:'Mirror-Mirror',
               path:'/profile',
               hiddenButtons: false
           })
       }
       if(b!==0) {
        const index = user.negativeRanked.findIndex(id => id === loggedInUser);
           console.log(user.negativeRanked,index, loggedInUser);
       }
}
    catch(error ) {
        console.log(error);
    }


}
```

The Idea is I want to render a page, but the "hiddenButtons" I want to be either false or true. If I find in that targetUser arrays the ID of the loggedInUser I want that hiddenButtons to be true and if not, false.

But when user is created both arrays positiveRanked and negativeRanked are empty. I have function to populate those arrays and it's working.

Can you please help me out to do that? Thank You!

the console.log display this

> ["5ce979c981d1fb079f8c1d2f"] -1 '5ce979c981d1fb079f8c1d2f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Mongoose` ObjectID is a custom type (because it uses the mongodb-native driver), so every `ObjectId` has a `.equals()` function that can be used to compare Object IDs:
`results.userId.equals(AnotherMongoDocument._id)`

You can also call the `.toString()` function of an ObjectID to transform it to string and compare it to another string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting an error because u are trying to compare mongo `ObjectID` to `string`.

`const index = user.negativeRanked.findIndex(id => id.toString() === loggedInUser)`